# slow query and "postgresql other" query in New Relic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, heroku, newrelic

I am having a bad time trying to find out why our application gets so slow when requests go up. It is a Rails 4 app, on Heroku. I am using New Relic to identify the problem but it does not really help me so far.

[image]

As you can see from this screenshot a huge number of calls to the DB are handled. And there is no such thing as 2000 calls in my controller! Anybody has got a similar issue lately?
I cannot find a good explanation about the "Postgresql Other".

[image]

I am pretty sure it does not come from my code, because most of it is used in other routes and there is this problem only on one...
I was just wondering if it could be linked to a problem with New Relic, as I already had that in the past.

ps: the 2 screenshots relate to the same method

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: hmm in my new_reliq i can click on the time of the query and it shows the stacktrace for that query. But you have a lot of `begin` and `commits`. It looks like db opens connection but does not need to do any updates because there were no changes. You can avoid this this `...save if <model>.changed?`

Comment: Do you have models without `created_at` and `updated_at` columns?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help guys, I found out what was the problem, it was indeed coming from my code, @Fallenhero led me on the good track. For any fellow in the future, here is the answer from New Relic about the Postgresql Other: 
"The Other operation is a catch-all for the various operations the Ruby agent does not recognize (i.e. a non SELECT, UPDATE, SHOW, FIND, DELETE, CREATE, INSERT operations)."
It was not clear because the operation WAS "update". My understanding is that "Postgresl Other" was catching all "wrong" updates: When the record was updated with the previous value (so it s not an really an update).